# How to update an object inside an array inside another array in a mongoose schema?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

found a lot of questions like these here, but not an answer.

### Problem

Lets say I have the following mongoose schema:

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sanePeoplesField: String,
  comments: [
    normalStuff: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    damNestedAgain: [String]
  ]
})
```

So to recap, `damNested array` is inside the `comments array` on the schema.

If I was lucky and wanted to change normalStuff (obj inside an array), I'd do this:

```
mySchema.findOneAndUpdate({"comments._id": req.body.commentId},
{
    $push:
    {
      comments: { normalStuff: 12122020 } }
    }
})
```

This would've updated normalStuff with a new value.

However, I need to update a field in `damNestedAgain`, but don't know how to reach it!

### Question

How to update the nested array of a nested array, `damNestedAgain`, in my example?

Answer (score 0):

```
mySchema.findOneAndUpdate({"comments._id": req.body.commentId},
{
    $push:
    {
      "comments.$.damNestedAgain": req.body.commentId
    }
})
```

That has done the trick, thanks.